# I need some help to understand this paragraph from Nicolai Josuttis book

Tags: c++, stream

I'd like to have some explanation regarding this paragraph on page 518 of Nicolai Josuttis book "The C++ Standard Library" (first edition):

> These flags are maintained by the class `basic_ios` and are thus present in all objects of type `basic_istream` or `basic_ostream`. However, the stream buffers don't have state flags. One stream buffer can be shared by multiple stream objects, so the flags only represent the state of the stream as found in the last operation. Even this is only the case if goodbit was set prior to this operation. Otherwise the flags may have been set by some earlier operation.

I don't understand what does he mean by "the stream buffer don't have state flags" and right below this paragraph there's a table with the title "Member functions for stream states".

Comment: What specifically are you having trouble with? There is a stream buffer, and it has no state flags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Streams consist of two objects:

1. The actual stream object (`std::istream` or `std::ostream`, derived from [`std::ios`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios)).
2. The stream buffer, i.e., a class derived from [`std::streambuf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_streambuf).

The state flags are present in `std::ios` but not in `std::streambuf`.

Comment: Could explain how a stream buffer can be shared by multiple stream objects.

Comment: @user1577873 Pointers are used to share single std::streambuf. Strictly speaking stream doesn't contain buffer, it just points to it.

Comment: @user1577873: You can create a stream from a `std::streambuf*`, e.g.: `std::ostream out(std::cout.rdbuf());`. With this, you can change the formatting of `out` to be different from `std::cout` and write to either `out` or `std::cout` to have characters appear at the destination where `std::cout` is writing to, using formatting as set up for the respective stream.

Answer (score 1):

There are "stream buffer objects", and a "stream objects". One stream buffer can be shared between multiple stream objects. Each stream object has its own set of flags - so one stream may be "reached end of file", where another is not - or the flags for output in decimal or hex may be completely different for two output streams using the same buffer.

[Of course, if you are using the same buffer for multiple streams, you will have to take care that you don't mess things up - and it's not a common thing to share the buffer over multiple streams, but it can be done!]

Comment: Using multiple streams with one buffer is an easy way to mingle different formats in the output… for example use one object to print some hex numbers and another to print some decimal ones. If the format is significantly different this is cleaner than trying to switch lots of flags back and forth each time.

Comment: @Potatoswatter Could you give a quick example on how to do this in your answer ?

Answer (score 1):

The `iostate` flags store things about output formatting: whether you want numbers printed in decimal or hex, capitals or lowercase, etc. Stream objects control formatting, so the flags are inside the stream object.

In iostreams, buffering is separate from formatting. Linked to the iostream object is a stream buffer object, which controls sending and/or receiving characters from an underlying source. The buffer object has no such flags; its only state variables deal with preparing (encoding) the characters and optionally storing (buffering) them to reduce the number of times the operating system is asked to perform I/O. (Or in the case of `stringstream`, the buffer provides the ultimate storage behind the stream.)

Comment: You mentioned on another answer that it's possible to use multiple streams with one buffer. Could you show a quick example ?

Comment: @user1577873 Since you didn't upvote anyone, I'm a bit less motivated.

Answer (score 1):

So a **stream** *has state flags*, but the **stream buffer** it uses *doesn't*.

A stream buffer goes inside a stream.

The buffer holds some amount of bytes that the stream is reading/writing before sending/recieving it to whatever the stream is talking to (file/stdin/tcpsocket/etc.).

Stream reference: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/iostream/

Stream Buffer Reference: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/streambuf/streambuf/

By default a stream will usually create it's own stream buffer, but you can tell it to use one of your choosing in the constructor: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/iostream/iostream/

Or you can get/set the buffer with the [rdbuf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/rdbuf/) method.

Comment: A stream buffer doesn't go inside a stream.  Although some derived streams do contain a stream buffer, the basic streams use a streambuf, without containing it.

Answer (score 0):

The "stream buffer" is an object of class basic_streambuf. That class doesn't have state flags. Every stream (basic_istream or basic_ostream) has a pointer to a basic_streambuf, but the flags are a property of the stream, not of the stream buffer.